# Working with objects in a calabash-cucumber

Tags: android, ios, ruby, cucumber, autotest

In the process of studying calabash-cucumber for testing mobile applications, the question arose how to work with objects. For testing took the application iOS, and here is one of the Activites has 4 questions and 3 answers to each question. To pass to the next Activiti, you need to answer these questions, and the answer is a checkmark of the option opposite the question. The picture looks like this:

```
|1|0|0| or |1|0|0|
|0|1|0| or |1|0|0|
|0|0|1| or |1|0|0|
|1|0|0| or |0|0|1|
```

1 - the selected option (check-box);

0 - not selected field.

There are no bindings to the button - neither ID nor text. We have to find it by coordinates. And here's the question: how to set an object (button) with given coordinates, and then pass it a method (for example, `object.touch(x, y)`) in the body of the step? There was an interest to check all the combinations, and there are 81 of them (in the steps it is very much) - it would be easier with the objects (you can write a counter for busting). Here are my attempts, but they do not work:

```
class Tapper
    def tap(x, y)
        perform_action('click_on_screen', x, y)
        #or touch(nil, {:offset => {:x => x.to_i, :y => y.to_i}})
    end
end

Then /^I touch on screen $/ do |x, y|
    @answer_1_1 = Tapper.new
    @answer_1_1.tap(802, 153)
end
```

The result is either:

> undefined step

or:

> undefined method 'perform_action' for Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calabash x-platform allows you to implement classes and object.

https://github.com/calabash/x-platform-example